# How do I pipe the Java console output to a file?

Tags: java, testing, logging, java-web-start

I found a bug in an application that completely freezes the JVM. The produced stacktrace would provide valuable information for the developers and I would like to retrieve it from the Java console. When the JVM crashes, the console is frozen and I cannot copy the contained text anymore.

Is there way to pipe the Java console directly to a file or some other means of accessing the console output of a Java application?

Update: I forgot to mention, without changing the code. I am a manual tester.

Update 2: This is under Windows XP and it's actually a web start application. Piping the output of

```
javaws jnlp-url
```

does not work (empty file).

Comment: By Java console do you mean the window opened when running a webstart application or applet?

Comment: Exactly. It's an option in the Java preferences.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually one can activate [tracing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html#tracing) in the Java Control Panel. This will pipe anything that ends up in the Java console in a tracing file.

The log files will end up in:

- <user.home>/.java/deployment/log on Unix/Linux
- <User Application Data Folder>\Sun\Java\Deployment\log on Windows
- /~/Library/Caches/Java/log on OS X

Comment: Can you tell us why the console froze?

Comment: Not really, I don't understand the stack trace all to good, as I am not a developer on this team. As far as I can tell, it is related to painting some components and the event-dispatch thread (as usual, haha).

Comment: Yup, I will do that, James. It's just that the system does not let you do that before 48 hours have passed.

Comment: On Os X 10.8.5, I found the log and trace at ~/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/log/

Comment: @TimDearborn The answer by Jan below points this out, you might want to upvote that one.

Answer (score 12):

(If you can modify the code) you can set the `System.out` field to a different value:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
```

If you are running a script (invoking the program via `java`) from `Unix` you could do:

```
/path/to/script.sh >& path/to/output.log
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: Without touching the code. Mea culpa!

Comment: Hmm. `System.out` is `final`, so you can't change it like that to use `PrintStream`.

You could use `System.setOut(...)` to do that, i.e.:
`System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));`

Comment: how to redirect exceptions stack trace in that file also ?

Answer (score 8):

In Mac 10.8.2 logs could be found at `/Users/<userName>/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/log/`.

Before you have to enable logging from Java Control Panel. Option "`Enable logging`" is at tab "`Advanced`". Java Control Panel could be started from "`System preferences`".

Answer (score 2):

A frozen console probably means a deadlock (it could also mean repeated throwing of an exception). You can get a stack dump using `jstack`. `jps` may make finding the process easier.

Answer (score 0):

try [this guide](http://seguide.blogspot.com/2010/02/writing-console-output-to-file-in-java.html) it works for me. it also guides you that how you can set "System.setOut(fileStream);", "System.setErr(fileStream);"