# where can I see exceptions thrown from within a java web start app?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm trying to debug a locally running java web start application. There is a call failing that I am trying to get a stack trace for, but it appears that nothing is ever getting printed out anywhere. The app just appears to be doing nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Control Panel in Windows you can start the Java control panel app. Then click on the "Advanced" tab, select "Java Console" and the select "Show Console". The stack trace will now appear in the console. I believe the console allows you to save the file to disk if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Logging java console output

[How do I pipe the Java console output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626389/how-do-i-pipe-the-java-console-output-to-a-file)