# Capture logging with Web Start on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I am running a java web start application. It crashes on start up. There's lots of useful information in the java console. However, once WebStart crashes, the console window closes and all my lovely logging information is gone. I haven't been able to find a way to capture that log info.

The web server, that's providing the web start code, delivers a file to the mac. I start the java app by clicking on the file. The splash screen comes up and then it crashes. Is there a simple way, with out changing the code in the java app to force the redirection of that output stream to a log file somewhere? I haven't been able to find any documentation that says this is possible.

I want all the information that gets printed to the java web start console screen, but in a file.

Comment: Trying to work this one out for myself, but no luck yet. Not seeing anything useful in the javaws manual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pipe the Java console output to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626389/how-do-i-pipe-the-java-console-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the Java control panel
2. Click on the Advanced tab
3. Under Debugging, enable tracing and logging
4. Run your JWS application (`javaws -viewer` is easy if it's already downloaded)
5. Let it crash or whatever
6. Find your log file in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/log`