# How Can I Pipe the Java Console Output to File Without Java Web Start?

Tags: java

I am wanting to pipe the Java console output (generated by `System.out.println` and its ilk) to a file. I found an excellent solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626536/531762) to enable Java tracing, but this isn't working for me (no log file shows up in any location on Mac OS X or Windows). From what I can tell, this is because I'm using a plain Java app without Java web start. So how can I do this with Java code that does not use Java web start? Ideally, I would like a solution that does not require modifying code.

Comment: Is there any way that I can do it without modifying code? I'd like to do it for an application that is already compiled, without having to recompile it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't require Java web start to do any of this. Just set the `System.out` to a `FileOutputStream`.

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
```

where `fileName` is the full path to the file you want to pipe to.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("home.txt")));
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

This will write `hello\n` to a file named `home.txt` in the current working directory.

If you can't modify code, on Windows 7, use [command redirection](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/redirect-command-output-to-file.htm).

```
java YourMainClass > home.txt
```

If you need to run a jar, you can use the `-jar` option of the [java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

```
java -jar /your/path.jar > /output/file/path.txt
```

Answer (score 23):

If you launch it from command line, then you can use redirect stdout and stderr into file as follows:

```
java -jar application.jar >file.txt  2>&1
```

where you have to replace *application.jar* with the jar file of your application.

Comment: Thanks. But: Why in the stderr?! I hope enough people already complaint about this..

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I can do it without modifying code? I'd like to do it for an application that is already compiled.

If you want to do it without changing code, then your best option is this:

```
$ java com.example.MyMainClass > filename
```

Comment: Tried `$ java /Applications/Test.app > ~/Desktop/Test.txt` on Mac OS X in the Terminal, but got "Error: Could not find or load main class .Applications.Test.app"

Comment: @Thunderforge - That is because you must provide a classname not a pathname.  Hint: a class name doesn't have slashes in it.  If this is confusing you, please take the time to read the manual entry for the `java` command.

Comment: Best I can tell from what I was thinking two and a half years ago, I was confused by the `some.pkg.App` being the name of an OS X app (which have the extension `.app`, equivalent to a Windows .exe). Since I was running a Java app packaged as a Mac OS X app, that's what I've tried. I've clarified your example to eliminate this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the problem in the background, do this -

```
nohup java -jar yourprogram.jar > log.txt 2>&1 &
```