# How to get output from runnable jar on PHP

Tags: java, php, web-services

I'm a student learning computer engineering.

today, I ran a runnable jar file from command line.

the runnable jar file contains only 5 line code like following.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and I could see "Hello World" from command line.

but when I ran the same runnable jar file from PHP I got only empty output.

this is the code from php

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("java -jar /Users/Test/Desktop/test.jar");
?>
```

How can I get output after running the jar file on PHP ?

Thanks in advance for your answer and sorry for my poor english. If you don't understand my question please make a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to put your Jar File inside the WWW folder and you will be get output.

```
<?php
    exec('java -jar search.jar -query "find my dog"', $output);
    print_r($output);

?>
```

Comment: why do we need to place the jar file in the document root ???
I got it to work only when i placed the jar file in the document root or www as you have said.

Answer (score 2):

You could redirect your output of the jar into a textfile like in this post:

[How Can I Pipe the Java Console Output to File Without Java Web Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669245/how-can-i-pipe-the-java-console-output-to-file-without-java-web-start)

So e.g.

```
java -jar /Users/Test/Desktop/test.jar >file.txt  2>&1
```

Then you can use busy waiting, to see whether the file is created or not, by calling :

```
while (! file_exists ( "/Users/Test/Desktop/file.txt" ) ){
  //do nothing
}
//now you can access the output of the file
```

This should work for your use case, but still you should reconsider your application design, because in a productive environment this will not scale.

Cheers

Comment: Is there another way to consider my app design for productive environment? I want to know that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get shell output, running commands with phpseclib. It's a bit more tricky but allows you to execute commands under another user (and also in another server if needed).

- create user with rights to run your jar
- create public/private key pair to that user
  give read access to your webserver to user's private key (that's why you don't want to use your personal user account)
- install phpseclib: add something like `"phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0"` to your
  **composer.json** and make **composer update** or use some other way to make it available to your code

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

$key = new RSA();
            
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('ssh_private_key_location'));

$ssh = new SSH2('server address/ip');

if (!$ssh->login('username'), $key)) {
    echo 'Login Failed';
} else {
    echo $ssh->exec('java -jar /path/to/test.jar');
}
```

If this code doesn't work out of the box, you can practice your investigation skills ;)