# Java Commons IO append multiple files

Tags: java, http, file-io, apache-commons-io

I am using Commons IO to download files from the internet.

This is the method i am using:

```
public void getFile(String url){

File f = new File("C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/hello.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    pw.close();
    URL url1;
    try {
        url1 = new URL(url);
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url1, f);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a way i can download multiple files using this method and have them all save to the hello.txt file? Using the above method, everything gets overwritten and the last file downloaded will be the one added to the hello.txt file.

Basically, is there a way i can store multiple file downloads in one file.

Thanks.

Comment: system.setOut() is good for piping in case it looks like you want 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669245/how-can-i-pipe-the-java-console-output-to-file-without-java-web-start

Comment: Yes, i know with Commons IO there is an append that you can add to the method but you cannot add it to the copyURLToFile method.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question; do you use Java 7+?

Comment: I did answer your question. Read above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way using `FileUtils`. However, if you want to use Apache Commons, I'd suggest you do the following:

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/hello.txt");
URL url1;
try {
    url1 = new URL(url);
    IOUtils.copy(url1.openStream(), new FileOutputStream(f, true));
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

which does more or less the same thing, but uses append mode on the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work. I have used your method but it still does not append to the file, it just overwrites it.

Comment: @user3080860 Whoops! I forgot to delete a line at the top... sorry about that. creating a new PrintWriter and closing it overwrites the file automatically. (I have edited my answer to remove that code).